# Key size of SHA512 hashing algorithm

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, sha

What is the key size of the SHA512 hashing algorithm?  I know that the final message digest is 512 bits.  I would like to know what key size it uses.  Thank you very much :)

Comment: If you want a keyed hash you should use HMAC-SHA-2 not SHA-2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash functions does not use key. It just map any input to one of 2^512 possible values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight :)  I appreciate it immensely :)

Answer (score 1):

What key? There is no key. It's a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying things to me :)  So that's why I could not find anything about key size when searching for SHA 512 hehe.